# Testing spring security with Postman

Tags: spring-security, postman

I have configured a form-base authentication using Spring security. It works fine when I log in using the login form in my web application.

It also works with cURL:

```
curl --data "j_username=myname&j_password=mypassword" http://localhost:8080/test/j_spring_security_check --verbose
```

However, I cannot make it works using Postman:

[image]

What is missing? I need to be authenticated in order to test other services.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I managed making Postman aware of authentication by using the [Postman Interceptor chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo)

With the extension enabled (by clicking the satellite icon within the Postman App), you just need to log in using the login form of your web and then you can start using services that require authentication in Postman.

Comment: Does this work with the Postman Native App (not chrome app) as well?

Comment: For this to work with Postman Native App, you must install the Interceptor Bridge: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor-extension/#using-the-interceptor-with-postmans-native-app

Comment: Well, for me it worked without the interceptor. How does this also solve the problem of authentication via postman?

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve authentication/authorization in postman through various authorization types given in postman dropdown under Authorization tab.

Below is the step to use **Basic Auth** which by default spring security provides.

In spring security you can customize your credentials in application.properties file as given below.

**spring.security.user.name=yer
spring.security.user.password=galem**

[image: Postman Spring security Basic Auth Form]

Answer (score 11):

Using **http.httpBasic** worked for me.

```
http.httpBasic()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/home")
    .hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/api/product/*")
    .hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and()
    .formLogin();
```

Answer (score 6):

**For me the Postman Interceptor was not working,** 
 So I did the following and now I can login to the server.

1. Select POST request from dropdown and type login URL in request URL section.
2. Select Body from tabs
3. Enter username and password keys and values as shown in picture.
4. And click send this will create a temp cookie in postman and be there for a session.
5. You can also do GET request for logout URL to logout from session. Or delete the cookie from Cookies below Send button.
   [image]

Comment: when i send post req with form data as you described i always get 404,. the same goes with x-www-form-urlencoded .but when i choose non-body, then i get bed credentials. all works fine with web browser.

Comment: i figured it out, postman has automatic redirection turn on. turing off, solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

When using basic auth on postman, you will set the credentials on the authorization tab.
Click on Authorization, choose the type as Basic Auth, the credentials section will be displayed for you to key in the username and password.

Answer (score 2):

`http.httpBasic` is working for Testing spring security with Postman.

For example, Added the override configure method from the configuration class MyConfiguration.java

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().permitAll().and().logout().permitAll().and().httpBasic();
        http.cors().disable().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Note: To access the `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` request you need to disable the `cors` and `csrf` as per code above.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

1. Create POST request to given security endpoint
2. Set j_username and j_password in the x-www-form-urlencoded tab:
   [image]
3. Put headers as follows:
   [image]
4. In the settings tab I disabled following redirects:
   [image]
   In that way when you call the request you will be able to check what was the result, for instance check the Set-Cookie Headers.

After calling this request you should be able to see the Set-Cookie and Location headers like:
[image]

This cookie which was just set should be used for all next requests for given domain. In that way those will be authenticated.