# How to auto generate postman collections from Spring environment

Tags: java, spring, postman

I have a requirement, where to test the performance of the application I need all the postman collections of the APIs which are being used in the process flow of the application to automate the flow.

I have seen this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/postman-testing-collections) in baeldung on how to generate a collection. In a similar manner, How can I get the output of all the APIs in the form of postman collections.

I'm using Spring MVC Legacy application with login, logout and dashboard JSP's with Rest APIs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether its Java/Spring or any other Tech Stack based web application, if the app is using REST Communication for API's, It can be tracked using Postman Interceptor. Its mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172150) answer. Once you install the extension in the browser and connect the Interceptor, you can intercept all requests which are being called through the browser, we can create a collection and save all the intercepted requests in the collection.

Comment: Is there a way to generate if from a new api? I am implementing new REST service. I already use `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` to generate swagger ui. And I use postman for tests. With time posman collection got pretty messy. I am Interesting if it would be possible to generate it.

Comment: If your new API is integrated in your browser, the postman interceptor will generate that API as well in the collection.